# Limiting the scope of "using namespace" in a header file

Tags: c++, namespaces, scope

I'm working on a small personal C++ project using STL. I don't like having "`std::`" all over the place in my header files, as I find it hinders readability, but at the same time I don't want to cause myself problems later on by putting `using namespace std` in a header file.

So I'm wondering if there's a way to limit the scope of the `using` declaration, so that it applies to the contents of my header file, but *doesn't* apply to files that include it. I tried various things like this

```
{
    using namespace std;

    // header file contents here
}
```

but it seems that introducing a scope this way is not allowed outside of a function definition. Is there a way to do what I'm after?

*Please note:* I'm really not interested in discussing whether this is a good idea, I just want to know if it can be done.

Comment: My erroneous answer has been deleted.  Apologies.  I always fully qualify names in headers (and even in cpp files now) out of habit.  It's pretty common to have code bases which declare their own vector, so it's helpful seeing std::vector to avoid the ambiguity.  This doesn't help answer your question though.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, I think that can be done.

In order to achieve that you need to build your own namespace.
I have written some code which is working as per the expected.

Header file looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
namespace my_space {
    using namespace std;

    void mprint ()
    {
        /*
         * This is working. It means we can access
         * std namespace inside my_space.
        */
        cout << "AAA" << endl; 
    }
};
```

Implementation file looks like:

```
#include "my_header.h"

int main ()
{

    /*
     * Working Fine.
    */
    my_space::mprint();

    /*
     * It gives a compile time error because
     * it can't access the std namespace
    */
    cout << "CHECK" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Please let me know if this does not satisfy your requirement. We can work out on that.

Comment: Note that this can have unintended consequences. By establishing a `using namespace blah;` within another namespace in a header file you're intentionally pulling in *everything* in that namespace that has been included in the current translation unit up to, and now including *your* header, but not further. A different translation unit including the same header can pull in declarations and definitions in the used namespace with the header (yours) being entirely unaware of that fact. It is one of the many reasons `using namspace` is ideally suited for establishing *after* all includes in a TU.

Comment: I might go with a solution like this, but the problem is that it pushes down the wrinkle in one place only for it to pop up in another. My header file code is nicely free of `std::`, but the code that uses it is peppered with `my_space::`. If I do `using namespace my_space`, this will import everything from `std` into the global namespace, which is what we were trying to avoid.

Comment: I agree with you Nathaniel. But you have to swallow the bitter pill at one place or the other.

Answer (score 3):

No, it cannot be done. Your attempt to introduce a scope in the header failed exactly because there is no such thing as a header scope - header files do not have a special status during compilation. The translation units are source file obtained after the preprocessor is done with it. Thus, all the `include` directives simply expand the corresponding header files. This prevents you from making the contents of the header file context-specific in any way.